# Is it Boundman or Bounceman?

Tags: one-piece

Luffy displayed Gear Four for the first time against Doflamingo and called it a specific form.  Via Funimation subs I thought this form was called Bounce Man.  The wiki calls it Boundman.

Is one of these two names offically correct? If Boundman is correct, what is this referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not watched One Piece, but after reading the [Gear Four Techniques wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi/Gear_Fourth_Techniques), both Boundman and Bounceman are appear correct - it is just a matter of how it is translated.

> **Boundman**
>
> Luffy's first Gear Fourth form is called Boundman (弾む男 (バウンドマン) Baundoman?, literal meaning "Bounce Man"; Viz and Funi subs: Bounce Man):

When plugging in [弾む男 (バウンドマン](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese%20to%20english&oq=japanese%20to%20english&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6439.8419.0.8506.19.8.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..19.0.0.chemjugbtEU) into Google's Japanese to English, it translates the text to

> Bouncy man (Bound man)

Comment: Just to extend that. The `tankuman` form is also pronounced `tankman` in case anyone was curious